# Submitting a form by pressing enter without a submit button

Tags: html, forms, submit

Well I am trying to submit a form by pressing enter but not displaying a submit button. I don't want to get into JavaScript if possible since I want everything to work on all browsers (the only JS way I know is with events).

Right now the form looks like this:

```
<form name="loginBox" target="#here" method="post">
    <input name="username" type="text" /><br />
    <input name="password" type="password" />
    <input type="submit" style="height: 0px; width: 0px; border: none; padding: 0px;" hidefocus="true" />
</form>
```

Which works pretty well. The submit button works when the user presses enter, and the button doesn't show in Firefox, IE, Safari, Opera and Chrome. However, I still don't like the solution since it is hard to know whether it will work on all platforms with all browsers.

Can anyone suggest a better method? Or is this about as good as it gets?

Comment: Small point that might shave a few characters off your CSS and will typically be done automatically be minifiers- you do not need units for zero length measurements. 0px = 0pt = 0em = 0em etc.

Comment: @pwdst thanks for pointing this out - I'm from the Python world, so "explicit is better than implicit", and genuinely wondering if this is the case in CSS, or do CSS creators have a different idiom?

Comment: Zero is the exception to the rule here @ericmjl - 0px == 0em == 0% == 0vh == 0vh etc. In other (non-zero) length measurements it is not only bad practice but against standards not to specify units and you'll see varying behaviour in user agents (browsers). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length and https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#lengths

Comment: If in doubt, put an explicit length unit in other words.

Comment: While it certainly doesn't hurt to add the unit with 0, not having any should be 100% valid regardless of  language, in fact all the way back up to mathematical abstractions. OTOH, a handy use of having vs. not having them is to convey the message whether the given property is "really meant to be 0, and stay that way" (no unit), vs. "that thing happens to be zero now, but might be adjusted to taste; or whatever..." (with unit).

Comment: Adding as a comment as it doesn't really answer the question, but for anyone looking; the default behaviour is for the form to submit on Enter ONLY if there's one input. More than one, and you'll need a submit button

Answer (score 313, accepted):

**Update 2022: Use this instead**

```
<input type="submit" hidden />
```

---

| Notice - Outdated answer |
| --- |
| Please do not use `position: absolute` in the year 2021+. It's recommended to use the `hidden` attribute instead. Otherwise, look down below and pick a better, more modern, answer. |

Try:

```
<input type="submit" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px"/>
```

That will push the button waaay to the left, out of the screen. The nice thing with this is, you'd get graceful degradation when CSS is disabled.

**Update - Workaround for IE7**

As suggested by Bryan Downing + with `tabindex` to prevent tab reach this button (by Ates Goral):

```
<input type="submit" 
       style="position: absolute; left: -9999px; width: 1px; height: 1px;"
       tabindex="-1" />
```

Comment: Anyone having trouble with this in IE 7? I get a huge submit bar that runs the entire width of the page with this solution. I've had to go the JS route as a result. Any suggestions?

Comment: Just tried this solution in IE7 with the same result as Erebus. The following code fixes it: `position: absolute; width: 1px; height: 1px; left: -9999px;`

Comment: What a horrible hack :( why is HTML like this in the first place? Is there a good reason for enter not to work in this case?

Comment: @nornagon: If you feel that this hack is horrible, feel free to suggest a less horrible one. HTML is what it is...

Comment: IMO, the OP's original solution is a lot more elegant than this one. It's only a different way to accomplish the same thing AND it had to be altered to keep browser compatibility which is what the OP wanted in the first place.

Comment: display:none; or visibility:hidden; are too clichè?

Comment: @Plokko Depending on the browser, some hidden elements are not entirely functional. The workaround is to push them out of the screen instead of hiding them.

Comment: Not very nice. You'll still be able to tab to the "hidden" button.

Comment: @MooseFactory `tabindex="-1"`

Comment: "the nice thing is ... graceful degradation when CSS is disabled"?! I mean sure, this works great, but the "graceful degradation" part is just marketing tactics. I hadn't even heard of it until I found [this page from the year 2002](http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum83/80.htm). That's right, the _only_ Google result on the first page for "css is disabled in the browser" is from _10 years ago_ (or 7 considering this answer was put up in 2009).

Comment: Working well, thx for this solution. For those asking about why not just "display:none": In chrome and FF 20 (I've only tested these two) if I hide the submit button with display:none, the onsubmit="..." attribute of the form is acting weird /e.g. doesn't respect "return false" and submitting the form anyway/. I've found it out in the hard way, I hope someone will learn from this.

Comment: @VickyChijwani You can end up with a page without CSS if you're on a slow connection and the loading of the CSS is taking time / is interrupted. You can still have a functioning [but ugly] page with graceful degradation. It's also about robustness, not just about 10 year old marketing fads.

Comment: yack, a little  of JS will do no harm

Comment: This is ugly nasty hack! But since it works perfectly, I'm going to stick with it and upvote this :)

Comment: @Vicky Chijwani graceful degradation might come handy for physically challenged and any software they use. This is a must for any government web, at least in most of the countries

Comment: Please do not use this in the year 2021+. Look down below and pick a better - more modern - answer. StackOverflow should really consider expiring thumb-ups after a while.

Comment: @Tafel Yeah, I wish answer authors had the option to un-accept their own answers. I could delete my answer, but then the advice against using this method would be destroyed. I'll add your comment as a notice at the top.

Answer (score 105):

I think you *should* go the Javascript route, or at least I would:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Using jQuery.

$(function() {
    $('form').each(function() {
        $(this).find('input').keypress(function(e) {
            // Enter pressed?
            if(e.which == 10 || e.which == 13) {
                this.form.submit();
            }
        });

        $(this).find('input[type=submit]').hide();
    });
});
</script>


<form name="loginBox" target="#here" method="post">
    <input name="username" type="text" /><br />
    <input name="password" type="password" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: nice one, tested and working fine. But before trying something like this, remember that submitting form via Javascript won't cause some browsers to offer the password saving stuff.

Comment: This will cause the submit button to appear for a moment (until the page loads and the JS runs).

Comment: A keypress is also triggered for a selection from autocomplete, i.e. if the user is inputting an email address and he/she selects a previously given one from the browser's autocomplete by hitting enter, then your form will submit. Not what your users will expect.

Comment: I switched to `keydown` from `keypress` for wider support, but you also need to add `e.preventDefault();` before the `if` if you hope to support Chrome.

Comment: I added a keyup binding to the form element instead of each input.

Comment: @Campbeln you may be able to use `.on('keypress'...)` instead.  The docs for `.on()` look like it does the `.preventDefault()` call for you.

Comment: I love the JavaScript route ;)

Answer (score 85):

Have you tried this ?

```
<input type="submit" style="visibility: hidden;" />
```

Since most browsers understand `visibility:hidden` and it doesn't really work like `display:none`, I'm guessing that it should be fine, though. Haven't really tested it myself, so CMIIW.

Comment: there's just one thing about `visibility: hidden`:
as you can read in [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp), _visibity:none_ still affects the layout. If you want to avoid this whitespace, the solution with absolute positioning seems to be better for me.

Comment: You can combine both solutions: `<input type="submit" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute;" />`

Comment: Damn it, this doesn't work in IE8 (it doesn't submit the form), so the solution from above wins: `position: absolute; left: -100px; width: 1px; height: 1px;`

Answer (score 41):

Another solution without the submit button:

HTML

```
<form>
  <input class="submit_on_enter" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search...">
</form>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.submit_on_enter').keydown(function(event) {
    // enter has keyCode = 13, change it if you want to use another button
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
      this.form.submit();
      return false;
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: Weird trick. That you make your button into a text box! But since the trick works for all the browsers, I have credited you!

Comment: thanks @JennaLeaf ;-) Anyway I think that it is not so weird - lot of online forms use as submit the simply "triggering" of the keydown. An example could be the google search-bar (perhaps they don't use exactly this code, but probably something similar).

Answer (score 33):

For anyone looking at this answer in future, HTML5 implements a new attribute for form elements, `hidden`, which will automatically apply `display:none` to your element.

e.g.

```
<input type="submit" hidden />
```

Comment: While it seems to work with desktop Chrome, it doesn't seem to work with Chrome or Safari on iPhone.

Comment: @UlfAdams It works with Chrome and Safari on iPhone 12.1.2.

Comment: unfortunately does not yet work in Safari 14.2 (macOS)

Comment: This correctly hides the submit button but disables "submit on enter". Does anyone know the browser compatibility of this? Looking at https://caniuse.com/hidden doesn't provide much info

Answer (score 14):

Use following code, this fixed my problem in all 3 browsers (FF, IE and Chrome):

```
<input  type="submit" name="update" value=" Apply " 
    style="position: absolute; height: 0px; width: 0px; border: none; padding: 0px;"
    hidefocus="true" tabindex="-1"/>
```

Add above line as a first line in your code with appropriate value of name and value.

Answer (score 10):

Just set the hidden attribute to true:

```
<form name="loginBox" target="#here" method="post">
    <input name="username" type="text" /><br />
    <input name="password" type="password" />
    <input type="submit" hidden="true" />
</form>
```

Comment: Attribute hidden will disable submit by pressing enter.

Comment: @66Ton99 Just test in FF. It do not disable submittion

Comment: "it works on my machine" ;) there are a lot more browsers than firefox. one can arguably want a solution that works reliably cross-browser wise.

Comment: Works on Chrome 63

Comment: Doesn't work in Chrome or Safari on iPhone at this time.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of the hack you currently use to hide the button, it would be much simpler to set `visibility: collapse;` in the style attribute. However, I would still recommend using a bit of simple Javascript to submit the form. As far as I understand, support for such things is ubiquitous nowadays.

Comment: Safari interprets `visibility: collapse` like `visibility: hidden`, so the button will still cause a white area: https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_visibility_collapse

Comment: Uff, that's bad. Apple need to get their shit together. Not only in violation of the standards, but also of the intuitive meaning of the words.

Answer (score 8):

The most elegant way of doing this is to keep the submit-button, but set it's border, padding and font-size to 0.

This will make the button dimensions 0x0.

```
<input type="submit" style="border:0; padding:0; font-size:0">
```

You can try this yourself, and by setting an outline to the element you will see a dot, which is the outside border "surrounding" the 0x0 px element.

No need for visibility:hidden, but if it makes you sleep at night, you can throw that in the mix as well.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0nkzme9L/)

Answer (score 7):

```
<input type="submit" style="display:none;"/>
```

This works fine and it is the most explicit version of what you're trying to achieve.

Note that there is a difference between `display:none` and `visibility:hidden` for other form elements.

Answer (score 7):

HTML5 solution

```
<input type="submit" hidden />
```

Comment: Same as above - doesn't work with Chrome or Safari on iPhone.

Answer (score 6):

IE doesn't allow pressing the ENTER key for form submission if the submit button is not visible, and the form has more than one field.  Give it what it wants by providing a 1x1 pixel transparent image as a submit button. Of course it will take up a pixel of the layout, but look what you have to do to hide it.

```
<input type="image" src="img/1x1trans.gif"/>
```

Answer (score 6):

I work with a bunch of UI frameworks.  Many of them have a built-in class you can use to visually hide things.

## Bootstrap

```html
<input type="submit" class="sr-only" tabindex="-1">
```

## Angular Material

```html
<input type="submit" class="cdk-visually-hidden" tabindex="-1">
```

Brilliant minds who created these frameworks have defined these styles as follows:

```css
.sr-only {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
    white-space: nowrap;
    border: 0;
}

.cdk-visually-hidden {
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is my solution, tested in Chrome, Firefox 6 and IE7+:

```
.hidden{
    height: 1px;
    width: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -100;
}
```

Comment: Seems like IE8 doesn't like position:absolute, it doesn't submit.

Answer (score 5):

the simplest way

```
<input type="submit" style="width:0px; height:0px; opacity:0;"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try also this

```
<INPUT TYPE="image" SRC="0piximage.gif" HEIGHT="0" WIDTH="0" BORDER="0">
```

You could include an image with width/height = 0 px

Comment: IMPORTANT: you MUST use a valid image URL or Firefox will show a "Submit Query" text on your page

Comment: If you add an image that exists and set height and width to zero, or add a non-existent image then the browser will have to make a wasted GET request for the resource.

Answer (score 3):

For those who have problems with IE and for others too.

```
{
    float: left;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: I'd still use position:absolute, float affects the layout.

Comment: Seems like IE8 doesn't like position:absolute, it doesn't submit.
I use:

Comment: Same for `float: left;`, when removed, it submits.

Answer (score 3):

```
input.on('keypress', function(event) {
    if ( event.which === 13 ) {
        form.submit();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: This works, if add the handler to each input that wish commit on enter. BTW, it's better to use `if (event.key === "Enter")` to check which the key is.

Answer (score 2):

I added it to a function on document ready. If there is no submit button on the form (all of my Jquery Dialog Forms don't have submit buttons), append it.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    addHiddenSubmitButtonsSoICanHitEnter();
});
function addHiddenSubmitButtonsSoICanHitEnter(){
    var hiddenSubmit = "<input type='submit' style='position: absolute; left: -9999px; width: 1px; height: 1px;' tabindex='-1'/>";
    $("form").each(function(i,el){
        if($(this).find(":submit").length==0)
            $(this).append(hiddenSubmit);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Modern answer for 2023 and beyond

The other answers are old or use jquery (which is also old and shouldn't be used in modern apps). keyCode is also deprecated and shouldn't be used.

```
<form id="myform">
  <input type="text" id="q" name="q" placeholder="Search...">
</form>

<script>
document.querySelector('#id').addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
  if(event.key === 'Enter'){
    document.querySelector('#myform').submit()
    return false
  }
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that worked to me sure it will help you

```html
<form name="loginBox" target="#here" method="post">
  <input name="username" type="text" /><br />
  <input name="password" type="password" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $("form").each(function () {
      $(this)
        .find("input")
        .keypress(function (e) {
          if (e.which == 10 || e.which == 13) {
            this.form.submit();
          }
        });
      $(this).find("input[type=submit]").hide();
    });
  });
</script>
```