# jquery-ui Dialog: Make a button in the dialog the default action (Enter key)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

In a jquery modal dialog, is there a way to select a button as the default action (action to execute when the user presses enter)?

Example of jquery web site: 
[jquery dialog modal message](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-message)

In the example above the dialog closes when the user presses Esc. I would like the "Ok" button action to be called when the user presses Enter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Submit jQuery UI dialog on <Enter>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/868889/submit-jquery-ui-dialog-on-enter)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In your dialog's open function, you can focus the button:

```
$("#myDialog").dialog({
    open: function() {
      $(this).parents('.ui-dialog-buttonpane button:eq(0)').focus(); 
    }
});
```

Change the `:eq(0)` if it's at a different index, or find by name, etc.

Comment: I just wrote the code to using $(this).parent().find('button:nth-child(1)').focus(); which is similar. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, I did open: `function() { $(this).parent().find('.ui-dialog-buttonpane button:eq(1)').focus(); }.`

Comment: I don't think this method works on newer versions of jQuery UI. The dialog's DOM now appears to have div.ui-dialog-buttonpane as a sibling, not a parent of $(this). Check out madeuz's answer below. zesc's answer will include the dialog's title bar "x". Gabriel's answer is basically the same as madeuz's, except the traversal is a bit different.

Comment: Any of the answer that use an event handler for keycode 13 are better than this since this only works when you only have buttons. If you want to have focus set to a different control than the default button this wont work. Darrens answer to use a form with a submit action may also be a better answer.

Comment: Doesn't work anymore but this does ... $('.ui-dialog :button').blur();
                    $('.ui-dialog :button:last').focus();

Comment: I found it worked but setting the focus is not the same as making the button default.   If there are other controls in the div then once they are selected the button will not have focus any more ?  Surely a keydown event is required ?

Comment: I had troubles with the initial selector provided here and ended up doing `$(".ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane button:eq(1)").focus();` to add autofocus to  other button (assuming there's two button choices) and this  works assuming there's only one modal element in the DOM. Nevertheless, this helps me out because I didn't know what to do before so thank you.

Answer (score 36):

I like this one (it is working for me), which leaves the focus where I wanted to be (a text box)

```
    $("#logonDialog").keydown(function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == $.ui.keyCode.ENTER) {
            $(this).parent()
                   .find("button:eq(0)").trigger("click");
            return false;
        }
    });
```

However, this is working just for one button (Ok button), if needed ':eq(n)' could be set to select other button.

**Note:** I added a new line returning false to prevent event bubbling when the enter key is handled, I hope it helps better than before.

Comment: This is the way to go. Setting focus (as shown in other solutions) will mess up power users who use tab to go to other fields and still want to hit "enter" anywhere in the form.

Comment: It is preferable to use [which](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/) instead of keyCode.

Comment: To get this to work, I had to change the action line to this: `$(this).parent().find('button:nth-child(1)').click();` Looks like the closer element already took the zeroth position!

Answer (score 20):

try this way:

```
$("#myDialog").dialog({
    open: function() {
         $(this).siblings('.ui-dialog-buttonpane').find('button:eq(1)').focus(); 
    }
});
```

Comment: This appears to match the DOM created by newer versions of jQuery UI (tested in 1.9.2) . Check out http://jsfiddle.net/KF3pp/1/ for a pattern that does not involve :eq(x)

Comment: Also, I believe this will work in any version of jQuery UI: $(this).parents('.ui-dialog').find('.ui-dialog-buttonpane button:eq(0)')  .

Comment: This also worked for me in jQuery UI 1.10.  The accepted answer did not.

Answer (score 12):

[This other stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/868889/submit-jquery-ui-dialog-on-enter) should get you where you want:

```
$('#DialogTag').keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        //Close dialog and/or submit here...
    }
});
```

Comment: I did not found the question before posting this question. It is definely almost the same question. Thanks for pointing it out. 
I tried to make this code work without to much success. I tried downloading the latest version of jqueryui and adding this code to the example (index.html), I did not manage to make it work.

Answer (score 10):

Another option that gives you more control over all buttons in the dialog is to add them as an array of buttons. Then in the **open event** you can get the buttons by id and do whatever you want (including **set the focus**)

```
$('#myDialog').dialog({
    buttons: [  
                {
                    id: "btnCancel",
                    text: "Cancel",
                    click: function(){
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                },
                {
                    id: "btnOne",
                    text: "Print One",
                    click: function () {
                        SomeFunction(1);
                    }
                },
                {
                    id: "btnTwo",
                    text: "Print Two",
                    click: function(){
                        SomeFunction(0);
                    }
                }
            ],
    open: function () {
        if ($('#hiddenBool').val() != 'True') {
            $('#btnOne').hide();
        }
        $("#btnTwo").focus();
    }
});
```

Comment: I couldn't get $("#btnTwo").focus(); to work to focus the button. Whoops. My bad. It did!

Answer (score 6):

A slight variation to use the buttons name as the selector. It reads a little better but there is obvious duplication with the button text string. Refactor to taste.

```
$("#confirm-dialog").dialog({
    buttons: {
        "Cancel" : function(){},
        "OK" : function(){}
    },
    open: function() {
        $(this).siblings('.ui-dialog-buttonpane').find("button:contains('OK')").focus(); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way would be to use the submit action on a form within the dialog, however:

- I did not want to require a form within dialog (N.B. different browsers handle the enter key differently, and some do not always do a submit on enter).
- I wanted this to work if the user clicks in the title pane or button pane prior to pressing enter.
- I wanted to make a library method that I can use for ANY
  jQueryUI dialog.

The company I work for is 'EBL' and I avoid global scope...hence the prefix on the functions below:

```
EBL.onUiDialogOpen = function (event, ui, hideX, actionFirstButtonOnEnterKey) {

    if (hideX) {
        // There is no option to hide the 'X' so override.
        $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
    }

    if (actionFirstButtonOnEnterKey) {
        /* (event.target) will give the div that will become the content 
        of a UI dialog, once div is 'opened' is it surrounded by a 
        parent div that contains title and buttonpane divs as well as 
        content div - so I use .parent()

        ...The keyup function is binded to all descendants, therefore:
              -We need the e.stopPropagation() line.
              -This code is NOT what you want if you DON'T want enter 
               key to initiate first button regardless of selected control.
        */
        $(event.target).parent().bind('keydown.justWhileOpen', function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.ENTER) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                $(event.target).next('.ui-dialog-buttonpane')
                    .find('button:first').click();
            }
        });
    }
};
```

...works in combination with:

```
EBL.onUiDialogClose = function (event, ui) {
    // Remove keyup handler when we close dialog
    $(event.target).parent().unbind('.justWhileOpen');
};
```

You do not need the .onUiDialogClose if you are using a dynamically created div and destroying it afterwards.

You can see below how I use these library functions when initialising a non-dynamic dialog...

```
$('#divName').dialog({
    //...
    open: function (event, ui) { EBL.onUiDialogOpen(event, ui, false, true); },
    close: function (event, ui) { EBL.onUiDialogClose(event, ui); },
    //...
});
```

So far I have tested this in IE9 and latest chrome/firefox.
You should validate the dialog as neccessary in your 'Ok' function.

Comment: You could hide the close-X with the following CSS, from the JQuery site: `.no-close .ui-dialog-titlebar-close { display: none; }` and then style the dialog like so: `$( "#dialog" ).dialog({ dialogClass: "no-close", ...`

Answer (score 1):

I'm using version 1.10.0. I could not get it to work with open but with focus. This focuses the second button:

```
focus: function(){
  $(this).siblings('.ui-dialog-buttonpane').find('button:eq(1)').focus();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#logonDialog").keydown(function (event) {if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        $(this).parent().find("button:eq(0)").trigger("click");
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me within the dialog using jquery 1.10.2

```
dialog({
    focus: function() {
        $(this).on("keyup", function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                $(this).parent().find("button:eq(1)").trigger("click");
                return false;
            }
        });
    },
```

more options...

Answer (score 0):

This simple piece of code styles your buttons and sets the default to the last one:

```
 open: function(){

      $buttonPane = $(this).next();
      $buttonPane.find('button:first').addClass('accept').addClass('ui-priority-secondary');
      $buttonPane.find('button:last').addClass('cancel').addClass('ui-state-default');
      $buttonPane.find('button:last').focus();

  },
```

Comment: This answer could be improved if it was in the context of jquery ui dialog.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, none of the answers worked because I called `.dialog` on an empty div and added my buttons ***dynamically***, so the `$(this).html()` would return nothing. So I couldn't call methods like `parent()` or `siblings()` and expect something in return. What I did was select the `ui-dialog-buttonpane` class directly and find the button element from there

HTML

```
<div id = "dialogexample">
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$("#dialogexample").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    open: function () {
        $('.ui-dialog-buttonpane').find('#otherbutton').focus();
    }
});
var buttons = {
    "MyButton" : {
        text: "Do Stuff",
        id: "dostuffbutton" 
    },
    "OtherButton" : {
        text: "Other Stuff",
        id: "otherbutton"
    }
} 
$("#dialogexample").dialog("option", "buttons", buttons);
$("#dialogexample").dialog("open"); //the second (otherbutton), instead of
                                    //the first (dostuffbutton) button should be focused
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but I was searching for this exact functionality and was able to implement what I think is the best solution as I found all of the above to fall short a little.

It is a combination of two answers above. Using an ID rather than relying on the find() function to find the button element always seems to be a much better choice to me.

Also explicitly looking for the enter key to be pressed allows us to set focus to whatever element we want when the dialog is opened if desired.  This just seems to allow for the most flexibility while satisfying the desire of triggering a specific button as 'default' when the enter key is pressed.  I have also implemented a 'cancel' default as well.

I hope this helps others looking for a good 'default' button solution for dialogs.

```
$("#LoginBox").dialog({
   open: function(){
      $(this).keydown(function (event) {
         if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            $("#LogInButton").trigger("click");
            return false;
         }
         if (event.keyCode == 27) {
            $("#CancelButton").trigger("click");
            return false;
         }
      });
   },
   close: function(){
      $(this).dialog("destroy");
   },
   buttons: [
      {
         id: "LogInButton",
         text: "Log In",
         click: function(){
            //button functionality goes here
            $(this).dialog("destroy");
         }
      },
      {
         id: "CancelButton",
         text: "Cancel",
         click: function(){
            $(this).dialog("destroy");
         }
      }
   ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should to use :tabbable selector and index of your button (0 is [X] button, yours started from 1)

```
open: function() {
    var tb = $(":tabbable", this.parentNode);
    if(tb.length>1) {
        tb[1].focus();
    }
}
```