# Detecting Enter pressed in AUI Dialog

Tags: javascript, html, liferay, liferay-aui

I want to detect if enter was used in html textfield i load into the Dialog.

If enter was pressed i want to simulate a click on the `Save`-Button.

i tried many things, basically pushing this code around:

```
 $(document).keypress(function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode == $.ui.keyCode.ENTER) {
        $("#resultTextArea").val("Enter gedrueckt");
            $(this).find("button:saveBtn").trigger("click");                                                                        
      }
});
```

Below is the AUI-Dialog (in which i tried above code)

```
          AUI().use('aui-dialog', 'liferay-portlet-url', function(A) {
                var dialog = new A.Dialog({
                                            title: 'New title',
                                            centered: true,
                                            modal: true,
                                            width: 500,
                                            height: 200,
                                            bodyContent:AUI().one('#addTestDialog'),
                                            buttons: [ 
                                                       { label : "Save" , id : "saveBtn" , handler : function(){ 
                                                            saveStuff();
                                                            this.close();
                                                        }
                                                       }
                                                        ],

                                            open: function() {
                                                $(document).keypress(function(e) {
                                                    if (e.keyCode == $.ui.keyCode.ENTER) {
                                                         $("#resultTextArea").val("Enter gedrueckt");
                                                        $(this).find("button:saveBtn").trigger("click");                                                                        
                                                    }
                                                });
                                            }

                }).render();
            });
```

And this is the html part that defines the body of the dialog:

```
<div style="display:none;">
  <div id="addTestDialog">

   <portlet:actionURL name="addNote" var="addNoteURL" />
    <br>
    <table style="width:100%;">
    <tr>
        <td>Name:</td>
        <td><input id="textInput" style="width:98%;height:20px;"></input></td>
    </tr>       
    </table> 
  </div>
</div>
```

I checked back with the API of AlloyUI and found this: http://deploy.alloyui.com/api/classes/Dialog.html

Under Attributes: There is no open which is used in every tutorial/code i found.
Therefore this cannot work (at least i think so). i tested initialize but this wont work either.

thank you for any help/hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **jQuery** to achieve this task

i.e

```
$("#saveBtn").keypress(function(event){
  var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if (keycode == '13') {
      // do what you want
    }
});
```

HTH

Comment: where do i need to put this? this does not work in the open function body

Comment: you can put this code outside aui block...and put alert inside this function to get notified that method called or not

Comment: this did not work for me. i put that codeblock below/after the  "AUI().use('aui-dialog', 'liferay-portlet-url', function(A) {}"

Comment: put my code inside this code $(document).ready(function() {
//my code
});

Comment: does not work because savebtn is the button i want to click via enterkey. therefore putting an enter detection on the btn makes no sense...

Comment: now i got it to work, changed savebtn to textInput and it works.

Answer (score 1):

It now works and this is my code (on enter pressed it does the same function as the savebtn and closes the dialog):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#scenario_add_btn").click(function(){             
     AUI().use('aui-dialog', 'liferay-portlet-url', function(A) {
       var dialog = new A.Dialog({
                                            title: 'New title',
                                            centered: true,
                                            modal: true,
                                            width: 500,
                                            height: 200,
                                            bodyContent:AUI().one('#addTestDialog'),
                                            buttons: [ 
                                                       { label : "Save" , id : "saveBtn" , handler : function(){ 
                                                            saveStuff();
                                                            this.close();
                                                        }
                                                       }
                                                        ]
                }).render();
                $("#textInput").keypress(function(event) {
                     var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
                    if (keycode == '13') {
                        saveStuff();
                        dialog.close();
                    }
                  });

            });



     });/*btn.click*/
});/*document ready*/
```

Answer (score 0):

The `keyCode` for enter is `13` try replacing `$.ui.keyCode.ENTER` with `13` and check if it works.

Comment: i just tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580304/confirm-jquery-ui-dialog-prompt-on-enter-key which uses 13 too. but that did not work either. tested 13 in my code (the one above), did not work

Comment: @Wandang can you tell  if there are any errors in the console?

Comment: there is no debugoutput. it just wont reach this line `   $("#resultTextArea").val("Enter gedrueckt");` which i use to debug.

Comment: try replacing `dialog` with `$(document)`.

Comment: still not working. i maybe found the reason why this wont work. gonna edit the original post

Comment: i am thankful for your effort but i only upvote answers that work. :/