# Why does my JQuery UI dialog not register keydown events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Following answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/868999/2148718), I wanted to hook the enter key press on a JQuery dialog so I can trigger the same event as when you click "OK", however the event is never called, and consequently I'm never getting the alert "it worked":

```
 $("#logout_popup").dialog(
                {
                    title: "Log Out",
                    width: 'auto',
                    height: 'auto',
                    modal: true,
                    draggable: false,
                    resizable: false,
                    open: function(e) {
                        $('.ui-widget-overlay').hide().fadeIn(600);

                        //This is the event that's never called
                        $(e.target).keydown(function(ev) {
                            alert("Worked!");
                        });
                    },
                    show: {
                        effect: 'fade',
                        duration: 600
                    },
                    hide: {
                        effect: 'fade',
                        duration: 600
                    },
                    buttons: [
                        {
                            text: "Yes",
                            click: logout
                        },
                        {
                            text: "No",
                            click: function() {
                                $('#logout_popup').dialog('close');
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    close: clear_forms
                });
```

Most of the dialog settings are irrelevant, but I included them all just in case. How come the event is never being called?

I should add that if I use the event `$("#logout_popup").keydown`, it also doesn't work, but if I use `$(document).keydown`, it does work (although I'd rather not have to filter every single event in the document.

Comment: How does the `dialog()` function look, how do you bind or pass the event to `open()`?  If I'm not mistaken...

Comment: Open (which is one of the fields of the object you pass in to dialog()) is automatically called by the JQuery library when the dialog is about to open.

Answer (score 0):

This would be the way to trigger the alert at least and catch the `event` of keydown (on some Element...)

```
open: function() {
    $('.ui-widget-overlay').hide().fadeIn(600);
    $('theElementYouWant').keydown(function(e) {
         alert("Worked!");
    });
},
```

If you want to pass the `keydown event` from down up, you should try

```
$("#logout_popup").keydown(function(e) {
  $(this).dialog({
           title: "Log Out",
           width: 'auto',
           height: 'auto',
           modal: true,
           draggable: false,
           resizable: false,
           open: function() {
             $('.ui-widget-overlay').hide().fadeIn(600);
             if ( e.which == 13 ) 
                   alert('Hurrah!');
           },
```

You can pass the event with `call(this,event)`, but I don't know wherefrom and when you want that.
From here: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-pass-event-target-to-a-function (@KevinB).
Call: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call.