# Enter click does not trigger JQuery dialog open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Me and a few co-workers are slightly puzzled by this issue. We have an onclick event in Javascript which opens a JQuery dialog box. This works when you actually click the designated button. However, when you press enter, it will trigger the onclick event and also perform the other required functions. But when it hits the dialog, it does not open. Strangely, if you insert an alert before the dialog code, it will open the alert and then open the dialog. Any fixes?

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#applyFilter').click(function () {
        console.log('event triggered');
        var suppString = $('#FK_SupplierID').val();
        var carryOn = true;
        //if the supplier ID fields is showing and populated:
        //check if supplier ID values are all numeric, if not show message and modal form
        if (suppString != null) {
            suppString.split(",").forEach(function (item) {
                if (item != '') {
                    if (!isInt(item)) {
                        //invalid value - set carryOn to false and exit the loop
                        carryOn = false;
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });

            if (!carryOn) {
                alert("The Supplier ID field must only have a whole number, or a comma-separated list of whole numbers.  Please type in a valid value or click the ellipsis button to select the required suppliers from the supplier list.")
                return false;
            } else {
                //check if supplier label is populated - if not, populate it
                if (suppString != '' && $('#suppliersShown').text() == '') {

                    //GetSupplierNames
                    $.getJSON("./GetSupplierNames", { ids: suppString },
                            function (data) {
                                $('#suppliersShown').text("Supplier(s):" + data);
                                $('#suppliersShown').show();
                            }
                        );
                }
            }
        }

        $('#dialog-processing').dialog({
            closeOnEscape: false,
            //open: function (event, ui) {
            //    $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
            //},
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 400,
            resizable: false,
            modal: true
        });

        $('#dialog-processing').dialog('open');

        var table = $('#invoiceTable').on('processing.dt', function (e, settings, processing) {

            //    $('#dialog-processing').dialog('close');

        }

).DataTable({
    retrieve: true,
});
        table.ajax.url('./FilterData/?filterString=' + FilterParams()).load(function (json) { console.log(json); });

    });
});able({
                retrieve: true,
            });
            table.ajax.url('./FilterData/?filterString=' + FilterParams()).load(function (json) { console.log(json); });

});
```

HTML:

```
<button id="applyFilter">click</button>
```

Comment: so the "even triggered" always shows up in the console?

Comment: What dialog plugin are you using?

Comment: @JonasGrumann Yes and we are using JQuery UI for the dialog. Version 1.11.4

Comment: I found a previous question that seems to relate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/868889/submit-jquery-ui-dialog-on-enter