# trigger two text field in rails at the same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have these two form with text field (I have a problem with the formatting in this editor, so the symbol of < is not written.

> %form_tag(:controller => 'mycontroller', :action => :myaction, :id => @my.id) do 
>       input class="mine" name="mine" type="text" size="10" 
>  
>       input class="his" name="his" type="text" size="10" 
>
>
>  
> %end%

and in the controller, i have

> def myaction 
> mine = params[:mine] 
> his
>   = params[:his]
>
> if (mine=="") or (his=="")
>   puts
>   "error" 
> else
>  if (mine) 
> puts
>   "textfield1"
>  end
>  
> if (his)
>  puts
>   "textfield2"
>  end 
>   
> end

I am confused with this. I need to put in each text field a value, and get the result of "textfield1" and "textfield2". 
But I recogn that if I press enter in the first textfield (mine), I will go to "textfield1" only. 
Is it possible to have in textfield 1 and textfield2 and get both condition executed with just one enter pressed (does not matter I am in the textfield1 or textfield2, but both will be executed if I press enter)?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Use {} icon for formating code, not "". Last one is for citing.

Comment: try putting a button by pressing it you can call both events.

Comment: If nothing has been filled into the second field, nothing will be submitted. What is it that you expect to receive in this situation?

Comment: I expect to show an error message if the second textfield is blank. So I want to get both value of both textfields at the same time (without any field is blank)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to submit both text fields use a single form. Any other solution would be an unnecessary hack.

[edit] Some browsers don't submit a form when *enter* is pressed if there is no submit button. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477691/html-submitting-a-form-by-pressing-enter-without-a-submit-button). As some answers say, you can try to hide it if you really want no button.

Comment: I tried to put both text field in the same form, but it caused that the enter did not work

Comment: @rahardi, update the question with that code. No reason enter does not work regardless the input fields the form includes.

Comment: I have updated it, does not work though.. I tried putting a button as harry said, and it works now. thank you

Comment: @rahardi: answer updated, I wasn't aware of that, the webkit browsers I use always submit on ENTER regardless there is a submit button or not.