# If I have an html form with one text input, does it submit when I press enter even if I don't have a submit button?

Tags: html, forms, button, submit, form-submit

When I have a submit button, it sends the form when I press enter.

Is the submit button necessary?

I am thinking of removing the button if it is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a `<form>`, one can submit by pressing the Enter key when you have a text input but **hide your submit button**.

```
<form action="wherever">
    <input type="text" name="input" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" style="display: none;" />
</form>
```

This type of buttonless interface may be useful in interfaces like a command prompt, but generally, users often recognize a form with a submit button.

Answer (score 2):

You need the `submit` button, otherwise the `input` is just an `input`.

Of course, you could use some javascript to force the submission, either `onblur` (when the `input` loses `focus`) or when the `enter key` is pressed.

However, I think this is a very bad idea from a user experience point of view.  People expect a `submit` button.

Here is another SO answer with some suggestions:

[Submitting a form by pressing enter without a submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477691/html-submitting-a-form-by-pressing-enter-without-a-submit-button)