# Submit form with Enter key without submit button?

Tags: jquery, html, forms, form-submit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HTML: Submitting a form by pressing enter without a submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477691/html-submitting-a-form-by-pressing-enter-without-a-submit-button)

How can I submit a form with just the Enter key on a text input field, without having to add a submit button?

I remember this worked in the past, but I tested it now and the form doesn't get submitted unless there's a submit-type input field inside it.

Answer (score 216, accepted):

```
$("input").keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("form").submit();
    }
});
```

Comment: Don't forget to add the # in front of the input id!

Comment: @MadsterMaddness Use the `#` only if we are specifying the ID of an element. From that answer, it specifies ALL the `<input>` elements.

Answer (score 49):

Change #form to your form's ID

```
$('#form input').keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        $('#form').submit();
    }
});
```

Or alternatively

```
$('input').keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        $(this).closest('form').submit();
    }
});
```

Comment: You can bind the keydown event on just the form, instead of binding the individual inputs: the keydown event will propagate up to the form.

Comment: very helpful indeed! makes sense not to have submit form buttons everywhere

Comment: If your form had multiple input elements then slightly better would be to bind the handler to the form and filter for events from input elements like this: $('#form').on('keydown', 'input', function(e) { ...

Answer (score 15):

Jay Gilford's answer will work, but I think really the easiest way is to just slap a `display: none;` on a submit button in the form.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I have to set visibility: hidden; instead.

Answer (score 5):

@JayGuilford's answer is a good one, but if you don't want a JS dependency, you could use a submit element and simply hide it using `display: none;`.