# How can I make a form submission by hitting the "Enter" key when the focus is on a particular item.?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, dojo

I am troubling with a small issue, which is a form submission by hitting the "Enter" key. Actually, it is working fine when I have one text field. But my issue how can I submit the form when I have all types of fields (Input text, Text area, drop down, radio button, check box, etc). I need to submit form when I hit the "Enter" key at a particular field.

Comment: Please provide some example code. What have you attempted?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help, you basically make the enter key submit a form not depending on the current focused field:
[Submit form with Enter key without submit button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981637/submit-form-with-enter-key)

Answer (score 0):

HTML forms submit automatically when you hit the enter key if

- The element with focus is a single-ling text field

AND

- The field is the only field in the form; OR
- The form has at least one button or an input with type=submit

In your case, you may include a button `<button type="submit">Submit</button>`, and you can hide it using CSS if you don't want it showing.