# Auto submit form on textbox change mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

So I have a requirement to auto submit a form upon edit of a set textbox within a form.

```
using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "refresh", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }, new { @id = "refresh" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary();
    @Html.TextBoxFor(modelitem => Model.Requirement)
}
```

How can I make that form submit to the controller method upon edit of the textbox?  (if  possible).

Comment: Is jQuery accepted? If so, you can add a listener on the targeted textbox and, say, on `enter` just call the `submit` on that form.

Comment: jQuery is completely fine, although im a complete beginner with it!

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/699065/submitting-a-form-on-enter-with-jquery) has what you need. Just change the selector (".input") to the id of your text box. Maybe [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981637/submit-form-with-enter-key) will help as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the jQuery solution this should work like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#Requirement').change(function () {
        $('#refresh').submit();
    });
</script>
```

The above will run when the text box loses focus (and had changed value), if you want to do it on every keypress you can replace `change` for `keyup` or `keydown` as you see fit.