# Submit form when press enter, not press button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code

```
<form name="frmDiagnosticos" id="frmDiagnosticos" method="post" action="agregarDiagnosticoSesion.jsp">
  <label for="txtCodigoCIE10" class="clase">Código CIE-10</label><input class="codigoCIE10" type="text" name="txtCodigoCIE10" id="txtCodigoCIE10" />
  <label for="linkAbrirBuscador" class="clase">Buscar código CIE-10</label><button id="linkAbrirBuscador">Buscar diagnósticos</button>
  <label for="chkCronica" class="clase">Enfermedad crónica</label><input type="checkbox" name="chkCronica" id="chkCronica" />
  <label for="chkHabito" class="clase">Es un hábito</label><input type="checkbox" name="chkHabito" id="chkHabito" />
  <input type="submit" name="btnConfirmarYContinuar" value="Confirmar" id="btnConfirmarYContinuar" />
</form>
```

When I am focused on the first text input (ID: `txtCodigoCIE10`) and I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, I want to trigger the event of the submit, not the button (ID: `linkAbrirBuscador`). How can I do?

I am using jQuery 1.11.

Comment: It working fine... check here http://jsfiddle.net/bw3Fs/

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981637/submit-form-with-enter-key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do like this :

```
$('#txtCodigoCIE10').keydown(function(e){
    var key = e.charCode ? e.charCode : e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : 0;
    if(key == 13) 
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('form').submit();
    }
});
```