# Enter key to submit form with javascript in case of multiply form with php id

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have separate reply form with each post with it's own php `$id` in same page. So I want to submit each reply with keyboard Enter key. I collect this javascript code below from here, but I cannot understand how apply it for each reply.

B.N: Collected code not working also.

my form:

```
<form action="" method="post" class="repfrm'.$id.'" id="prepfrm">
<textarea name="replycom" id="replycom'.$id.'" class="replycom"></textarea>
<button type="submit" name="submit" id="'.$id.'" class="replyfrm">Post Reply</button>
</form>
```

Collected Script From stockoverflow:

```
$(".replycom").keyup(function(event){
   if(event.keyCode == 13){
       $(".replyfrm").click();
   }
});
```

Comment: Use that http://stackoverflow.com/a/8981665/4478897 and modify using .closest("form").submit();

Comment: If you change the `textarea` to an `input type="text"` you'll get this behaviour by default without the need for JavaScript.

Comment: why not `$(".replyfrm").trigger('click');` ??

Comment: Tushar Raj, $(".replyfrm").trigger('click'); working but submit all reply.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that:

Bind keypress to textarea and submit the closest form when press the key

```
$("textarea").keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest("form").submit();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this script

```
 $(".replycom").keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            $(this).parents('form').submit();
        }

    });
```

Comment: i think he wants to submit the form with the Intro/Enter key

Answer (score 0):

Change  `textarea` to `textbox` and you press enter in textBox then it works which you want. Do not required `jQuery` code.

```
<form action="" method="post" class="repfrm'.$id.'" id="prepfrm">
   <input type="text" name="replycom" id="replycom'.$id.'" class="replycom">
   <button type="submit" name="submit" id="'.$id.'" class="replyfrm">Post Reply</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I have some css code with textarea, also I used $('textarea').elastic(); for auto height. so maybe I cannot change textarea to textbox. But I will try it also. Thank U.