# How to submit with Enter key?

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 submit button in 1 form.
I want to chose second button on enter.
On enter Browser default is chose first button.
How to codeing  chose second button on enter ?

```
<form name"form1">
<input type="submit" name="button1" id="button1" value="Submit">
<input type="submit" name="button2" id="button2" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: try changing the type of the first button from "submit" to "button".

Comment: No, i use  2 summit in 1 form  not use with type button.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Submit form with Enter key without submit button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981637/submit-form-with-enter-key-without-submit-button)

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="button" name="submit">Submit</button>
<input type="submit" name="pasok">
```

maybe that's what BPS is saying to you