# rails simpleform press enter instead of button for submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, simple-form-for

I have comments for posts in a rails site.

Here is my _form.html.slim for my "make a new comment" form.

I would like pressing the enter key to submit the form and the submit button to be hidden/not displayed.

Is this possible within simpleform?

```
span = simple_form_for([@post, @post.comments.build], :defaults => { :input_html => { :class => "comment-input-text" } }) do |f|
  = f.input :comment, label: false, placeholder: "Add a comment"
  = f.submit
```

Sorry, I could not convert this code the any erb or html. If anyone would like to edit this question and put in the erb it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, its duplicate question

Check this link: [Submit form with Enter key without submit button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981637/submit-form-with-enter-key)

You can add this right below form

```
javascript:

  $("input").keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("form_id_here").submit();
    }
  });
```