# Login using enter key

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have login form in my app. Currrently I have a Login button to login. When this login button is clicked, I send the username and password values to the backend api which in turn generates a token and allow the user to move to next screen if authenticated. I want the same functionality when I press enter key. I have looked to many sources but I need a secure way. How can I do it. This is my form component

```
render(){
    return (
        <div className="LoginPage">
            <div className="login-page">
                <div className="form">
                    <form className="login-form">
                        <input id="username" type="username" placeholder="username"/>
                        <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="password"/>
                        <p className="message">Not registered? <a href="#">Request Username and Password</a></p>
                    </form>
                    <button onClick={this.handleLoginButtonClick.bind(this)}>login</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Is your solution working ? What problems does it have?

Comment: you need to bind key press event to form or its input elements see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981637/submit-form-with-enter-key-without-submit-button

Comment: How can I do it using just javascript? Also I if a user just enters username and not the password and hits enter key then password field should get focused asking him to enter the password. can you please suggest me something for all of  this?

Comment: yes use the event in above url ans and check for your input value if not has a value then focus on that element

Comment: You can just add the `onSubmit` attribute to the form like this `<form className="login-form" onSubmit={this.handleLoginButtonClick.bind(this)}>` and then change the button to the submit type. You will have to then use `preventDefault()` in the `handleLoginButtonClick`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `onKeyDown` event with `input` fields, and in this `method` check the `keycode` of the `key` pressed by the user, `Key code of Enter key is 13`, so whenever he pressed `enter`, call the same method that you are calling on `button` click, Write it like this:

```
render(){
    return (
        <div className="LoginPage">
            <div className="login-page">
                <div className="form">
                    <form className="login-form">
                        <input id="username" type="username" placeholder="username" onKeyDown={this.onKeyDown.bind(this)}/>
                        <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="password" onKeyDown={this.onKeyDown.bind(this)}/>
                        <p className="message">Not registered? <a href="#">Request Username and Password</a></p>
                    </form>
                    <button onClick={this.handleLoginButtonClick.bind(this)}>login</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

onKeyDown(e){
   if(e.keyCode == 13){
     /*write the logic here*/
   }
}
```

You need to use `ref` to focus the field if user left them blank.
Check `jsfiddle` for working example with focusing the field:  https://jsfiddle.net/ygytaj6s/

Comment: How can I make a field focused if user hasn't anything in the field?

Comment: check `jsfiddle` for complete working example, focusing part also, please mark the ans as correct it solved ur isssue :)

Comment: let me know if you need any help in this :)

Comment: use `autoFocus` property to focus any field by default :) check this one: https://jsfiddle.net/d3gbjuew/ name field is autofocused.