# Jquery trigger enter and clicked button functionality on form

Tags: jquery

I am working on a form and in that form button is disabled by starting and after filling the form button will get able to submit it. Now, I want that after filling the form the user should be able to submit the form by clicking enter button as well and it should validate if the all the fields are filled or not as well. I want this functionality with Jquery only.

Thanks in advance.

Here is the code on which I want this to be:-

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="form-group"> 
    <label for="URL">Website - (Optional Field)</label> 
    <input class="form-control" id="URL" placeholder="www.example.com" type="url"> 
    </div> 
    <div class="form-group"> 
    <label for="Legal_Name">Name</label> 
    <input class="form-control" id="Legal_Name" placeholder="Enter Your Legal Name" type="text"> 
    </div> 
    <div class="form-group"> <label for="Doing_Business">Doing As - (Common Name) </label> 
    <input class="form-control" id="Doing" type="email"> 
    </div> 
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default section_btn section-5-next hover_ease btn_disable">Next</button>

    </body>
    </html>
```

```
<script>$('.section-5-next').click(function(){
    $('.section-5').hide();
        $('.section-6').fadeIn();
        $('.Progress_Status').html('35%').css({'width':'35%'});
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I have answered your question, but don't know why it got down vote. So have you checked it? Hope it will give you what you want.

Comment: I have checked it. It is working on button click but not on enter press.

Comment: ok @nishant, I have updated my answer. You can check it now. I changed jquery selector to `form-control` class instead of `input`.

Comment: sorry!! but still it is not working

Comment: Have you placed all these code inside document.ready function?

Comment: I have again updated my answer to show you the whole `<script>` JS code snippet. Take a look.

Comment: Thanks the code is working nice now but it is submitting the form even without any field filled. How can I validate if all the fields are filled or not now?

Comment: You can add `required` attribute for the inputs. By the way, as my answer has solved your main question, can you accept it please?

Comment: I want it from jQuery if it is possible. Sorry for the troube but I have just started learning jQuery

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this using jquery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.section-5-next').click(function(){
        $('.section-5').hide();
        $('.section-6').fadeIn();
        $('.Progress_Status').html('35%').css({'width':'35%'});
    });
    $('.form-control').keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
          $('form').submit();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you explain, why down vote? Downvote without explanation is not useful.

Comment: I perceived he just joined

Comment: @SamuelJames, I did not get you.

Comment: He's still new may be the reason for down vote. Your solution is elegant

Comment: @nishant, as my answer has solved your main question, can you accept it please? And as you want to validate your form using jquery, you need to use jquery's validator plugin/library. [Here is the example](https://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/akPoad).

Comment: @nishant, this answer was accepted before. You removed it ?

Comment: yea because I have accepted by mistake at that time @HimanshuUpadhyay

Comment: @nishant, ok, but my answer had solved the issue you mentioned in your question.

Comment: read it properly man I have said it is working but without validation and in code description I have clearly stated that I want something with validation and this is not what I want. @HimanshuUpadhyay

Answer (score 0):

Check this [Submit form with Enter key without submit button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981637/submit-form-with-enter-key-without-submit-button)

```
$("input").keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#formtosubmit").submit();
    }
});
```