# How to use enter button from keyboard as submit

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio, javascript-objects

I'm making a todo list using javaScript,HTML and CSS and for insert any element we have to click on submit(add) button but i want that when we press enter button from keyboard the element will insert or the submit button will press and i don't have any idea how to do that because i am new in javascript

---

Here is the Code

---

HTML

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
</head>
<body>
<input id="task"><button id="add">Add</button>
<hr>
<div id="todos"></div>

<script src="nv.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Java Script

```
function get_todos() {
  var todos = new Array;
  var todos_str = localStorage.getItem('todo');
  if (todos_str !== null) {
      todos = JSON.parse(todos_str); 
  }
  return todos;
}

function add() {
  var task = document.getElementById('task').value;

  var todos = get_todos();
  todos.push(task);
  localStorage.setItem('todo', JSON.stringify(todos));

  show();

  return false;
}

function remove() {
  var id = this.getAttribute('id');
  var todos = get_todos();
  todos.splice(id, 1);
  localStorage.setItem('todo', JSON.stringify(todos));

  show();

  return false;
}

function show() {
  var todos = get_todos();

  var html = '<ul>';
  for(var i=0; i<todos.length; i++) {
      html += '<li>' + todos[i] + '<button class="remove" id="' + i  + '">x</button></li>';
  };
  html += '</ul>';

  document.getElementById('todos').innerHTML = html;

  var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('remove');
  for (var i=0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
      buttons[i].addEventListener('click', remove);
  };
}

document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click', add);
show();
```

---

Thanks

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981637/submit-form-with-enter-key-without-submit-button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to add `onkeypress` event to the `task` input as below:-

HTML

```
<input id="task" onkeypress="enterToSubmit(event)">
```

---

Javascript:

```
function enterToSubmit(event){
    var key = event.keyCode;
    if(key===13){
        add();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `keydown` and trigger click when press enter key

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
         document.getElementById('add').clock();
    }
});

function get_todos() {
  var todos = new Array;
  var todos_str = localStorage.getItem('todo');
  if (todos_str !== null) {
      todos = JSON.parse(todos_str); 
  }
  return todos;
}

function add() {
  var task = document.getElementById('task').value;

  var todos = get_todos();
  todos.push(task);
  localStorage.setItem('todo', JSON.stringify(todos));

  show();

  return false;
}

function remove() {
  var id = this.getAttribute('id');
  var todos = get_todos();
  todos.splice(id, 1);
  localStorage.setItem('todo', JSON.stringify(todos));

  show();

  return false;
}

function show() {
  var todos = get_todos();

  var html = '<ul>';
  for(var i=0; i<todos.length; i++) {
      html += '<li>' + todos[i] + '<button class="remove" id="' + i  + '">x</button></li>';
  };
  html += '</ul>';

  document.getElementById('todos').innerHTML = html;

  var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('remove');
  for (var i=0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
      buttons[i].addEventListener('click', remove);
  };
}

document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click', add);
show();
```

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
</head>
<body>
<input id="task"><button id="add">Add</button>
<hr>
<div id="todos"></div>

<script src="nv.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can execute a function whenever the user releases a button press on keyboard e.g

```
<input id="myInput" value="Some text..">

<script>
var input = document.getElementById("myInput");
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
   event.preventDefault();
   document.getElementById("myBtn").click();
  }
});
</script>
```