# Submit a form with link as button using Enter key

Tags: javascript, html, enter

Hi i'm currentyl having an issue with a form on a website, im using a link  instead of a button or an input to submit a form, but i cannot seem to make it submit when the user press the enter key, the Form values are being validated using javascript with the following format 
onsubmit="return function();"

Anybody knows how to make it submit on enter keypress ?

Thanks

Comment: why don't you style the button to look like a link? :)

Comment: Submitting a form by pressing enter :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477691/submitting-a-form-by-pressing-enter-without-a-submit-button

Comment: Thanks @epascarello it worked flawlessly haven't tought about it :) 
This is what i wanted to achieve http://jsfiddle.net/5vHGc/52/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try capturing the event.keyCode property when hitting a key on the particular link.

```
   $('#example').keyup(function(event) {
      if(event.keyCode === 13) {
        //do what you want
        **EDIT:** $('$FormName').submit();
      }
   });
```