# HTML form is not working with table inside

Tags: html, html-table

Here I placed the *table* inside *form* to arrange the form items.
It does not work even though it is valid.

```
<form method="get" action="another.php">
<table width="50%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
    <td width="60%">
        Number: <input type="text" name="number" />
    </td>
    <td width="20%" align="center">
        Title: <input type="text" name="title" />
    </td>
    <td width="20%">
        Short Desc: <input type="text" name="shortdesc" />
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

When I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the form won't submit.
where as if I place a submit button anywhere inside the form, it works for both <kbd>Enter</kbd> key and Button click.

```
<input type = "submit" value="Submit" />
```

But I don't want any buttons for submissions. I Submit the form by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.
Any clues why this doesn't work ?

Comment: Does it do what you want without the table markup?

Comment: use <input type = "submit" value="Submit" style="display: none" />

Comment: I tried this. If i hide the submit button, it is not submitting again.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477691/submitting-a-form-by-pressing-enter-without-a-submit-button

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to your form

```
<input type="submit" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px"/>
```

or

```
<input type="submit" style="visibility: hidden;"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this ....will fix your problem for all three browser

```
 <input  type="submit" name="update" value=" Apply " 
style="position: absolute; height: 0px; width: 0px; border: none; padding: 0px;"
hidefocus="true" tabindex="-1"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

all forms need a submit button to be submitted (without javascript atleast):

you can make it invisible:

```
<input type="submit" style="visibility:hidden"/>
```