# Is it possible to submit an html form without using an input button?

Tags: jquery, html, html-select, html-input

I found this article (http://www.developertutorials.com/tutorials/javascript/javascript-form-submission-no-button-050412-1292/), but it is 8 years old (c. 96 in Internet and duckbilled Platypus years).

strager's answer here: [Submitting a form by pressing enter without a submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477691/submitting-a-form-by-pressing-enter-without-a-submit-button) indicates that it might be as easy as calling "this.form.submit();" in a selection's event (onChanged() or whatever).

Is that so? Or not so? Or so not so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true. You can generally call submit() on a form on *any* event, as long as you identify the form clearly. @pXL uses jQuery syntax for that; my only caution is that you need to make certain there's only one form on the page, because jQuery fires the handler on *the list* of elements its selector returns. Either name the form

```
$('form[name=theOne]')
```

or use an Array accessor

```
$('form')[0]
```

You can make it fire on keyUp in a field (you could test the key value to match 'return'), or even if the user clicks somewhere outside the form.

```
$('html').click(function(){$('form')[0].submit()});
```

(This is probably not the best user experience, though!)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can submit the form using `.submit()` *no need of submit button*

Html :

```
<form action="some.php" method="get">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname">
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname">
</form>
```

JS:

```
$('form').submit();
```

Demo `--->` http://jsfiddle.net/PqXWJ/19/

Comment: Are you sure that's the right jsfiddle? It seems much more involved and not necessarily related.

Comment: @ClayShannon , Actually i updated one of the fiddle i was working on - anyway, you can see this demo `--->` http://jsfiddle.net/PqXWJ/19/

Comment: I get, "{"error": "Please use POST request"}"

Changing the jQuery to post, it seems to work.

Strangely, I also experimented with changing the action. With action set to "/" and using ".submit()", the results pane becomes a complete jsfiddle page in a pane.