# Yii CActiveForm submit on enter press

Tags: php, forms, yii, onclick, enter

I'm using Yii framework and I have a lot of CActiveForms.
On some of them, when I click <kbd>Enter</kbd> it submits the form, on the others it doesn't submit.

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Ps: I'm not using any code to prevent that the submition on <kbd>Enter</kbd> press.

Comment: would you present some code?

Comment: Post Some code where you are getting the error

Comment: Do you have submit button on all forms? Without code we can as well read from tea leaves. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477691/submitting-a-form-by-pressing-enter-without-a-submit-button?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the HTML5 autofocus attribute (works in all current browsers except IE8 and IE9).

```
 <input type="text" name="myField" autofocus />
```