# How to hide submit_tag button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an simple form:

```
<%= form_tag icd_test_path, :method => 'get', remote: true do %>
<%= hidden_field_tag(:sicherheit) %>
<%= hidden_field_tag(:id) %>
<%= submit_tag "", :id => 'Scomit' %>
<% end %>
```

How you can see both text_fields are hidden, now search an way to hide the submit_tag as well?It want the form hidden because its only triggerd by jquery!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Adding display none to the submit tag should do the trick.

```
<%= form_tag icd_test_path, :method => 'get', remote: true do %>
<%= hidden_field_tag(:sicherheit) %>
<%= hidden_field_tag(:id) %>
<%= submit_tag "", :id => 'Scomit', :style => "display: none;" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477691/submitting-a-form-by-pressing-enter-without-a-submit-button) seems to indicate style="visibility: hidden;" is more cross-browser friendly.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer writing raw HTML in this type situation. It is a lot cleaner.

```html
<input type="submit" id="Scomit" style="display:none">
```