# Phonegap - app works on desktop, not on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I have created a web app using HTML, CSS and JS. In previous stages of the app, I have successfully loaded it on to my phone using Phonegap Build, and it "worked" there (still had a ton of bugs). 
 
Now, I have fixed all the bugs and made the app prettier, and **it works perfectly on my computer** (even in chrome's device simulation with my phone's model in there).
The thing is, when I use Phonegap Build just like I did before, in my phone, the app doesn't respond, and it doesn't work. That made me wonder: 
 
Are there some limitations to what you can do with Phonegap? Or whatever works on the desktop should work too? 
To see exactly what's going on, I added a `#console` element to the DOM, and logged there in every action. It seems that the `$(document).ready()` is working, but that's pretty much it. It doesn't respond to clicks, nor to form submits.
I cannot post the code here because it's way too long.

Comment: How did you bind your Onclick function?

Comment: Using jQuery, nothing special: `$('#watched').click(function() ...`

Comment: I don't know how much you know about Phonegap, do you know DeviceReady function in Phonegap? That is the only thing i can think of

Comment: @TonyChen I replaced jQuery's `$(document).ready()` function with deviceready, and added a script linking to phonegap.js, but nothing has changed. Bummer.

Comment: I don't mean to replaced it. I think you should bind the function after DeviceReady. Or you may send your code to me if it's OK~~ I will try

Comment: BTW my email: chendatony31 at gmail

Comment: Have you used "deviceready" event listener

Comment: @Tony I sent the files to your email.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i have build a android app with your code.

Because I use `cordova` so I change your phonegap.js into cordova.js and it works well.

[image]

Comment: Oh man, it still doesn't work on my Android device. It's frustrating.

Comment: I sent my www files to your email.

Comment: @Gofilord Hi, i seem to find out what is wrong... You submit button which is `display:none` is not working on mobile

Comment: you should read about this :[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477691/submitting-a-form-by-pressing-enter-without-a-submit-button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477691/submitting-a-form-by-pressing-enter-without-a-submit-button)