# type=button and type=submit with pressing enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button

I noticed that when I create a button with type=button (on an example login button) to script it with JavaScript without refreshing the page, then I can't press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to move forward.

Is there a workaround?

Comment: `keydown` will serve you here. Keycode 13 is the enter-key

Comment: Do you want to intercept the submit event to do something without actually posting to the action specified in the form?

Comment: Paste some code so we can see what's really bothering you.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13){
      $('.button').trigger('click');
    }
  });
  
  $('.button').on('click', function() {
    alert('hi');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text"/>
<input type="button" class="button" value="BUTTON"/>
```

Comment: The OP doesn't want a submit button. This is effectively a submit button that is dependent on several thousand lines of script rather than none at all (see answers to [*Submitting a form by pressing enter without a submit button*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477691/submitting-a-form-by-pressing-enter-without-a-submit-button)).