# What triggers Html.beginform() to submit?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, form-submit, html.beginform

What are all the triggers that will trigger the submit if I have a page that has this form on it?

*NOTICE - I only have a text field and NO submit button.

Will the submit occur when I press enter and the cursor is in the text field?

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home", FormMethod.Get, new { @class = "navbar-form navbar-left", role = "search", id = "queryWithin" })) {
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" id="searchQuery" name="searchQuery">
</div>

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have button at all - no your form will not submit.

You either should use **javascript for submit on enter press event** or there is a [really neet hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/477699/1849444) how you can hide your submit button from user, but don't hide it from key press event.

Just quote solution here:

```
<input type="submit" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so , you should have submit button and also your form method should be `FormMethod.Post` not `FormMethod.Get`

Comment: Isnt the difference between GET and POST in the way the URL is generated , caching of parameter, data length, etc.
Is there a specific reason why you want the user to use POST as opposed to GET?

Comment: maybe this link would be helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477333/what-is-the-difference-between-post-and-get