# Send through input value to javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a `form` like below:

```
<form onsubmit="doSomething(this.form);">
    <input type="text" name="groupName" />
    <input type="text" name="groupColour" />
</form>
```

Now this doesn't have a submit button, I know. Instead, when the user hits the enter key I want it to trigger a function. In this example `doSomething`.

Now in the function I will performing an AJAX request to insert a record to the database, however I'm not sure how to access the value that was entered in the text fields in my AJAX function `doSomething`.

How do I pass to my function the values of the form when submitted?

Comment: depends if you are using jquery or not, but query the textboxes you want to pull the data from, then either use pure javascript has method  .value  or jquery has  .val()   for getting the input value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `onsubmit` attribute. [Divide your HTML and javascript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) and handle form submission using jQuery.

```
$("form").on('keypress', function(event){
    // if the key is "enter":
    if(event.which == 13) {
        // trigger AJAX:
        $.ajax({
            url     : 'post-page.php',
            type    : 'post',
            // serialize the form (all the form fields will be posted to PHP):
            data    : $(this).serialize(),
            success : function(response){
                // handle server response...
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**[HTML & JQuery fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pwwxpxbv/2/)**

Because you're using jquery and you want to use ajax request, you can use `keypress` function instead of form and submit :

**HTML :**

```
<input type="text" id="groupName" />
<input type="text" id="groupColour" />
```

**JS :**

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) { //When you pressed enter!
        var name = $('#groupName').val();
        var color = $('#groupColour').val();

        $.post('insert.php',{name: name, color: color});
    }
});
```

**PHP (insert.php) :**

```
$name = $_POST['name'];  //Get name
$color = $_POST['color'];  //Get color

//Now you can use $name & $color in insert Query here
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477691/submitting-a-form-by-pressing-enter-without-a-submit-button) it works.. Do this tricky :-)

```
<form onsubmit="doSomething();">

    <input type="text" name="groupName" />

    <input type="text" name="groupColour" />

   <input type="submit" 
   style="position: absolute; left: -9999px; width: 1px; height: 1px;"
   tabindex="-1" />

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Heres a easy way..

```js
document.onkeypress =function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
       alert(document.forms['myform'].elements['myinput'].value);
    }
};
```

```html
<body>
  <form name="myform">
    <input name="myinput" type="text" value="awesome">
    </form>
  </body>
```