# Webform onSubmit not working with more that on input in React

Tags: meteor, reactjs, meteor-react

I have a react component in meteor with a webform in. The following code works fine and prints hello addtile in the console:

```
export default  class NewTileForm extends Component {
  addTile(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("hello addtile")
  }
 render(){
    return(
        <div>
          <form className="tile-new" onSubmit={this.addTile.bind(this)}>
            <input  type="text"
                    ref="tile"
                    placeholder="Tile Title"/>
          </form>
        </div>
     )
  }
}
```

However, if I try to add a input to the webform I get no response from the console log:

```
 export default  class NewTileForm extends Component {
  addTile(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("hello addtile")
  }
 render(){
    return(
        <div>
          <form className="tile-new" onSubmit={this.addTile.bind(this)}>
            <input  type="text"
                    ref="tile"
                    placeholder="Tile Title"/>
            <input  type="text"
                    ref="company"
                    placeholder="Tile Company"/>
          </form>
        </div>
     )
  }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: how are you submitting the form? with the enter key?. Also, what happens the other way (include company, but remove tile)

Comment: I'm submitting with enter. and if I remove tile and include company only, it works as well.. But with two input field it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is "a browser thing" - you can't submit a form with the enter key and without a submit or button. No it's not react specific. To be honest, not sure why it worked with one - not sure the caveat there.

Anywho, Stackoverflow has lots of answers about tackling this issue (when you remove react as the problem):

[Submitting a form by pressing enter without a submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477691/submitting-a-form-by-pressing-enter-without-a-submit-button)

Comment: Thanks. Yes the issue was that the form needs a submit button.