# Why addEventListener("submit") doesn't work when the form has two text inputs?

Tags: javascript, html

With one text input in the form, the following code works fine to submit the form once the ENTER key is hit:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
<script>
    document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit"); 
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="myForm" action="#" method="post">
    First Name: <input type="text" name="fname"> 
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

However, with two text input fields, the following code does not work. That is, After hitting ENTER, nothing happens.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
<script>
    document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit"); 
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="myForm" action="#" method="post">
    First Name: <input type="text" name="fname"> <br>
    Last Name:  <input type="text" name="lname">  
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

My question is not a duplicate of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477691/submitting-a-form-by-pressing-enter-without-a-submit-button), which addressed how to hide the submit button. My question is: Why addEventListener("submit") doesn't work (i.e., the from cannot be submitted) when the form has two text inputs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Submitting a form by pressing enter without a submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477691/submitting-a-form-by-pressing-enter-without-a-submit-button)

Comment: The link you provided addresses how to hide the submit button, which is different from my question. I am asking why addEventListener("submit") doesn't work when I have two text inputs.

Comment: `addEventListener` doesn't work in either case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element

Answer (score 4):

See the HTML spec, specifically [4.10.21.2. Implicit submission](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sec-forms.html#implicit-submission):

> If the form has no Submit Button, then the implicit submission mechanism must do nothing if the form has more than one field that blocks implicit submission

and

> an element is a field that blocks implicit submission of a form element if it is an input element whose form owner is that form element

Your form has two input elements and no submit button.

Add a submit button.

Comment: To add, if you don't want to display the submit button, just add `display:none` in a css class or inline style.