# Submiting form with "Enter" button doesn't work

Tags: html, forms

I have this html form and I would like to make it run by pressing Enter:  a

```
                        <form id="login" name="login2" action="" data-action="" method="post">
                        <div class="error-message js-error-message"></div>
                        <fieldset>
                            <label for="signin_input_loginid">Login</label>
                            <span class="corner-wrapper">
                                <input type="text" name="username" value="" class="trans-02s trans-color trans-box-shadow" id="username">
                                <span class="corner corner-top-left"></span>
                                <span class="corner corner-top-right"></span>
                                <span class="corner corner-bottom-left"></span>
                                <span class="corner corner-bottom-right"></span>
                            </span>
                            <label for="signin_input_password">Password</label>
                            <span class="corner-wrapper">
                                <input type="password" name="password" value="" class="trans-02s trans-color trans-box-shadow" id="signin_input_password">
                                <span class="corner corner-top-left"></span>
                                <span class="corner corner-top-right"></span>
                                <span class="corner corner-bottom-left"></span>
                                <span class="corner corner-bottom-right"></span>
                            </span>
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset class="clearfix">
                            <div class="f-left remember clearfix">
                                <label class="f-left">Remember me?</label>
                                <div class="toggle-wrapper checkbox-slider f-left off">
                                    <div class="button trans-02s trans-left"></div>
                                    <span class="choice-1 choice trans-02s trans-color trans-text-shadow">No</span>
                                    <span class="choice-2 choice trans-02s trans-color trans-text-shadow">Yes</span>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="remember" value="0">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <span class="submit-wrapper f-right" style="margin-top: 14px;">
                                <span class="submit-hover trans-02s trans-opacity"></span>
                                <input type="" onclick="login_g2();" value="Login" class="lbut trans-02s trans-color trans-background">
                            </span>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
```

And I've tried to add different scripts or change the form etc. But it doesn't work. I can't launch submit by pressing enter:

```
    <script>
//submit the form
$( "#login" ).submit(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
     </script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Submitting a form by pressing enter without a submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477691/submitting-a-form-by-pressing-enter-without-a-submit-button)

Answer (score 1):

*Preventing default* is not the best idea in this problem.

Try to use this jquery solution.

```
   $(function() {
    $("form input").keypress(function (e) {
        if ((e.which && e.which == 13) || (e.keyCode && e.keyCode == 13)) {
            $('button[type=submit] .default').click();
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    });
});
```