# Can't submit form using enter in safari browser

Tags: html, safari

I have normal get form

```
<form action="{{url('/products_search')}}" method="get" class="position-relative" id="search_form">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control search_loading" name="input_search" style="text-align: left !important;" value="{{$input_search ?? ''}}" placeholder="Find Your Products..." required>
        <button type="submit" style="display: none;"> </button>
</form>
```

When I hit enter in all browser it submit   but in safari  it doesn't work like I clicked nothing

How to make the form submit on Enter ?

Comment: The problem may be `display: none;` try `visibility: hidden; width: 0; height: 0; overflow: hidden;`

Answer (score 4):

If the button inside the form is hidden, that does not work in Safari.

You can try the solution here. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/477699

It hides the button by moving it off the visible screen.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is missing a closing tag to your div:

```
<div class="input-group">
```

The invalid html being generated might be an issue?

Comment: I just removed some codes  but  it works on all other browsers also missing tags won't effect the form submission

Comment: Safari 11.1.2 on MacOS 10.13.6 does attempt to submit for me, pressing enter, based on your code sample above. There must be something else in your code, that I can't see.