# Submit form without button in selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, htmlunit-driver

On the page I want to test I have a form like this:

```
<form method="post" action="target.html">
    <input id="myInputField" />
</form>
```

A normal use-case here would be that the user enters some text and then hits enter.
For testing I tried sending the Special-Key "enter" but that results in an exception:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Cannot locate element used to submit form
```

Is there a way to submit a form without having a button present? I am testing headless with HtmlUnitDriver.

Comment: Try <input type="text" id="myInputField" />

Comment: Unfortunately setting the type for the text-field does not help selenium find the "submit"-Element for the form (which does not even exist in this case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a little workaround I got it to work:
Creating the submit button but setting the display to none does the trick. But I am still searching for a better solution

```
<form ...>
...
<input type="submit" style="display:none" />
...
</form>
```

Now the send()-Method can find the submit-Element.

Answer (score 0):

Have you also tried

```
.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN)
```

instead of `.ENTER`?  
If this doesn't work I think the [answer of @fuzzi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63378606/7430010) is the best way or take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/477699/7430010)!

Comment: I just did, but it's the same result: ```Cannot locate element used to submit form```

Comment: Then you're simply missing a `<input type="submit"/>` which would enable entering the values without a button.

Comment: That is exactly what I did in the answer I posted below. But in my opinion it is just a workaround and should work without. Or maybe it is just not possible with selenium.