# How can I submit <form>'s data without <button> in HTML?

Tags: html, button, submit, action

As I am beginner in HTML, could someone make a logical explanation on the following? I can submit data using `<button type="submit">`, but if I had a single `<form type="text">`, I could submit it just by pressing `enter`.

As I failed to gather any info on that, does someone know how does it happen? Wouldn't it make sense to always have a button that would *submit*, and not also waiting for the *user's enter*? It feels as if *enter* on keyboard is same as *button submit*. Example:

```
<form action="https://www.youtube.com/results">
    <input type="text" name="search_query">
    <button>Submit me!</button>
</form>
```

This one also works by pressing just *enter*:

```
<form action="https://www.youtube.com/results">
    <input type="text" name="search_query">
</form>
```

P.S. Of course on both these input types we have to type **dog**.

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+submit+html+form+by+pressing+enter) of [Submitting a form by pressing enter without a submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/q/477691/4642212), but it depends on your exact requirements; e.g. there’s a way to do this with or without JavaScript, do it well or do it badly, etc.

Comment: I can't understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can submit the form on an event with javascript like this:

```js
document.getElementById("myFormId").submit();
```

If you want to disable the submitting of a form on enter, you can also do this with JS.

```js
document.getElementById("myFormId").onkeypress = function(e) {  
//When key is pressed in form
  if (e.keyCode == 13){
  //If key is equal to enter (key code 13)
    e.preventDefault();
    //Prevent the default action (submitting the form)
  }
}
```